# Standard Naming Convention for DAO Methods

Tags: java, design-patterns, naming-conventions, dao

Is there a standard naming convention for DAO methods, similar to JavaBeans?

For example, one naming convention I've seen is to use `get()` to return a single entity and `find()` to return a List of entities.

If there isn't one, what's the one your team is using and why?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Usually I name the methods in such way that the name hints the type of the CRUD operation that will be applied by the method, like `add*`, `save*` or `find*`.

- `add*` can be applied on `INSERT` operations, like `addPhoneNumber(Long userId)`.
- `get*` can be applied for `SELECT` operations, like `getEmailAddress(Long userId)`.
- `set*` can be applied on method that performs an `UPDATE` operation.
- `delete*` can be applied on `DELETE` operations, like `deleteUser(Long userId)`. Althought I'm not pretty sure how useful is the physical delete. Personally, I would set a flag that denotes that the row is not gonna be used, rather than performing a physical delete.
- `is*` can be applied on a method that check something, for example `isUsernameAvailable(String username)`.

Comment: I personnaly also use descriptive names on methods like findAll* to add more intent information

Comment: When going to DAO layer, we should not use the same naming as in Model. Instead of 'get' use 'find', instead of 'set' and 'add' use 'update'. Also try to be more Object Orientated passing the model object when possible, specially to update methods.

Answer (score 23):

I am aware of conventions like the following:

- methods starting with `find` perform `select` operations, and method names containing the search criteria, like `findById`, `findByUsername`, `findByFirstNameAndLastName`, etc.
- modification methods start with `create`, `update`, `delete`.

Check out the conventions used by [Spring Data JPA](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.0.0.M2/reference/pdf/spring-data-jpa-reference.pdf). This is part of the Spring framework that writes the DAOs automatically based on among other things inspection of the method name based on naming conventions.

`get()` for single entities does not seem to be a good option, as get is associated by Java developers to a Java-bean getter.

Comment: much agreed : find is much better than get (it always makes me think of a getter). Also excellent to add search criteria in the method names.

Comment: What about situations where you are returning a F.Promise<SomeObject>? Would your findByUsername become findByUsernameAsync? Thanks.