# php, jquery and ajax - populating select dropdown based on previous selected value

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have been told my previous post wasn't very clear, so I am going to try to ask it in a different way.

I am working in an OOP recipe book. At the moment, I I am working on adding recipes. For that, I am displaying a dropdown list of measurements, when the user selects the measurement, I want to display another dropdown with the units found for that measurement_id.

The tables on mysql are measurements, with id and name column, and units, with id, name and measurement_id column (measurement_id is the foreign key for the units table). Multiple units will belong to one measurement.

For that, I have created a measurement php object/class.

On new_recipe.php, I include a form, with the rest of columns to add a recipe, I will include only the matter I am treating now:

NOTE: on measurement.php, the Measurement php object/class has those methods:
- display_measurements() --> Just selects ALL measurements from the measurements table.
- get_units_for_measurement($measurement_id) --> Selects ALL units with the same measurement_id.

```
public function display_measurements() {
      include 'includes/db_connection.php';   
          try {

      $sql = "SELECT id, name FROM measurements";

      $results = $conn->prepare($sql);
      $results->execute();
     } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . '<br />';
        return array();
    }
      return $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }


   public function get_units_for_measurement($measurement_id = ':measurement_id') {
       include 'includes/db_connection.php';

       try { 
           $sql = "SELECT measurements.id, units.id, units.name "
               . "FROM measurements "
               . "JOIN units "
               . "ON measurements.id=units.measurement_id WHERE measurements.id=:measurement_id";
           $result = $conn->prepare($sql);
           $result->bindParam(':measurement_id', $measurement_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
           $result->execute(); 
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . '<br />';
        return array();
    }
    return $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

 <form id="newRecipe" method="POST" action="new_recipe.php">   
(...)
     <div class="input_group">
         <label for="name" class="required">Name</label>
         <input name="name" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="input_group">
         <label for="measurements" class="required">Measurements</label>  
         <select name="measurements" class="selectMeasurement">
             <option disabled selected value=""> -- select a measurement -- </option>
<?php
$measurements = $measurementObj->display_measurements();
foreach ($measurements as $measurement) {
    echo '<option value="' . $measurement['id'] . '" ';
    echo '>' . $measurement['name'] . '</option>';
}
?>
       </select>        
   </div>
   <div class="input_group">
       <label for="units" class="required">Units</label>
       <select id="selectUnit" name="units">
           <option disabled selected value=""> -- select a unit -- </option>
             <?php
             if (isset($_POST['measurements'])) {
                 die('ddddd');
                // $units = $measurementObj->get_units_for_measurement($_POST['measurements']);
            //     foreach ($units as $unit) {
            //         echo '<option value="' . $unit['id'] . '" ';
            //         echo '>' . $unit['name'] . '</option>';
            //     }
             }
             ?>
       </select> 
   </div>
   (...)
   <button class="submit" type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

You can see, in the form, two select dropdowns; the first one is the one where I am displaying the measurements, and the next one, that I have with some commented lines, is where I am suposed to "filter" the measurement_id selected in the first dropdown to display the belonging units.To do it not reloading the page, I was advised to do it with ajax (which I am not very familiar with). This ajax call in on a js file, linked to the footer of the project:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#newRecipe').on('change','.selectMeasurement', function(){
      var selectedMeasurementId = this.value;
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'classes/measurement.php',
            data: selectedMeasurementId
        });
        return true;
    });   
});
```

or
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#newRecipe').on('change','.selectMeasurement', function(){
          var selectedMeasurementId = this.value;
            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'classes/measurement.php',
                data: selectedMeasurementId,
                success: function() {
                    alert(selectedMeasurementId);
                }
            });
        });
    });

In the js file, what I had in mind was on success, call the method object:

success: $measurementObj->get_units_for_measurement($_POST['measurements']), and I understand, if I have an ajax response, I want to get the units for the given measurement, but, I can't call a PHP object in here.

Also, I tried to do something when the measurements is set. After the select for the measurements I tried to do:

```
 if (isset($_POST['measurements'])) {
  //then $measurementObbj->get_units_for_measurement|($_POST['measurements']), but it seems it does not "detect" the measurements has been set. 
}
```

So my question is.... how can I execute this $measurementObj->get_units_for_measurement(measurement_id selected in the first dropdown), for the success of the ajax request?

I hope it is a bit clearer now. 
Thank you

Comment: Hmm.. it's very confusing to just understand your question.

Comment: You have a few things mixed with each other. first what you have in this file: `classes/measurement.php`? is it the _ measurement class_ or a file which is responsible to get the `ajax` request and send back the data which ajax asked for?

Comment: ohm.... it is the _measurement class. Should I rename the file in another way? I was actually looking if it is common to name the file with capital, as the class, but I didn't find anything so I just named with the class name. The file responsible for the ajax request is, at the moment, just on the footer ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Disclaimer:*** this is a just a rough and untested sketch of how you can do it.

As you mentioned OOP, I would first refactor how you access the database to be more object-oriented. I am going to use a shortened version of a DAO pattern. If you follow [certain conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20447682/1022914), it makes it very easy to use. There are few drawbacks with this pattern, but for the most part it keeps your code more organized.

First, I would create two classes `MeasurementDAO` and `UnitDAO` that will be used for accessing data for each table, respectively. (You could just use one class if it is more convenient for you.)

**classes/MeasurementDAO.php**

```
class MeasurementDAO
{
    protected $conn;

    public function __construct(PDO $conn) {
        $this->conn = $conn;
    }

    public function getMeasurements() {
        try {
            // no need to use prepare() if you are not using any placeholders e.g. :name or ?
            // query() and prepare() do not return results, but a (st)atement (h)andler
            $sth = $this->conn->query("SELECT id, name FROM measurements");
            return $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . '<br />';
        }
    }
}
```

**classes/UnitDAO.php**

```
class UnitDAO
{
    protected $conn;

    public function __construct(PDO $conn) {
        $this->conn = $conn;
    }

    public function getUnitsByMeasurement($measurementId) {
        try { 
            // if I am not mistaken, this query should be shorter and equivalent to your initial one
            $sth = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM units WHERE measurement_id = ?");
            // I have never seen any reason to use bindParam() as you can just pass your values in execute()
            $sth->execute(array($measurementId));
            return $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . '<br />';
        }
    }
}
```

(You'll probably also want a **RecipeDAO.php** with methods such as `getRecipes()`, `addRecipe($recipe)`, `updateRecipe($recipe)`, `deleteRecipe($id)`.)

Next, when you make an AJAX request to a script, you don't want to directly call the class. Instead you want to call a script that uses the class.

**ajaxHandler.php**

```
// this will hold the data to be sent back as our response
$res = array();
// initialize connection
$conn = new PDO(/*...*/);
// determine what action to take
if ($_GET['action'] === 'get_units') {
    // get units
    $res['units'] = (new UnitDAO($conn))->getUnitsByMeasurement($_GET['measurement']);
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
// last line: send response (it should be the only thing that gets outputted)
echo json_encode($res);
```

You would call the script from your JavaScript by going to e.g. `ajaxHandler.php?action=get_units&measurement=123`.

Next, we would get the measurements using our new way. (I personally find its better and cleaner to do all the database stuff at the beginning -- opposed to doing it as you are outputting HTML.)

**new_recipe.php**

```
<?php
// initialize connection
$conn = new PDO(/*...*/);
// get measurements
$measurements = (new MeasurementDAO($conn))->getMeasurements();
?>

<form id="newRecipe" method="POST" action="new_recipe.php">
    <!-- etc -->
    <div class="input_group">
        <!-- sidenote: label's FOR attribute attaches itself to the inputs's ID attribute, not NAME attribute --> 
        <label for="measurements" class="required">Measurements</label>  
        <select name="measurements" class="selectMeasurement">
            <option disabled selected value=""> -- select a measurement -- </option>
            <?php if ($measurements) : ?>
                <?php foreach ($measurements as $measurement) : ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $measurement->id ?>"><?php echo $measurement->name ?></option>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            <?php endif ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="input_group">
        <label for="units" class="required">Units</label>
        <select name="units" id="selectUnit">
            <option disabled selected value=""> -- select a unit -- </option>
        </select> 
    </div>
    <!-- etc -->
</form>
```

Finally, let's call the ajax handling script and build the list of options.

```
// shorter syntax for $(document).ready
$(function() {
    $('#newRecipe').on('change', '[name=measurements]', function () {
        console.log('send request with ', this.value);
        // we'll use a $.getJSON() which is a shortened version of $.ajax() 
        // make a GET request to ajaxHandler.php?action=get_units&measurement={this.value}
        $.getJSON('ajaxHandler.php', { action: 'get_units', measurement: this.value }, function (res) {
            console.log('got response', res);
            var html = '';
            // build list of options if any
            if (!$.isEmptyObject(res.units)) {
                $.each(res.units, function (unit) {
                    html += '<option>' + unit.name + '</option>';
                });
            }
            // set list of options
            $('[name=units]').html(html);
        });
    });   
});
```

That should be it. You'll need to add the missing parts such as including the PHP files.

(If you want to keep your current setup, just follow everything from **ajaxHandler.php** and make the necessary adjustments.)